# Form loaded with ajax call not having autocomplete enabled

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have a form (loaded by obiumap function) that have a section loaded ( by function obiumap_addobj() ) with a $.ajax call from jQuery script (addobj.js) by clicking a button (addobj_btn). This new section is loaded in an

existing div (addobj-container) but without autocomplete functionality and also without default_value.

This is main form:

```
function obiumap($form, &$form_state) {
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', $this->modName) . '/addobj.js');
global $user;

$form=array();
$form['uid'] = array(
'#type' => 'hidden',
'#title' => 'uid',
'#default_value' => '3',
'#id' => 'uid',
);  
$form=array();
$form['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'name',
'#id' => 'name',
);  
$form['addobj_btn'] = array(
     '#type' => 'button',
     '#value' => t('Add new objects'),
     '#id' => 'addobj_btn'
);  
$form['addobj-container'] = array(
        '#markup' =>  '<div id="addobj-container" ></div>'
);
die(drupal_render_children($form));
}
```

This is section definition loaded via ajax:

```
function obiumap_addobj($form, &$form_state){
global $user;
$form=array();
$form['uid'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'uid',
'#default_value' => '10',
'#id' => 'uid',
);  
$form['fldset_addobj'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Add new object'),
'#collapsible' => TRUE,
'#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
$form['fldset_addobj']['objname'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#id' => 'objname',
'#title' => t('Object name'),
'#autocomplete_path' => 'obimap/obiumap_addobj',
'#required' => TRUE,
);
 $form['fldset_addobj']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Add object',
'#id' => 'addobj_btn'
);
die(drupal_render_children($form));
}
```

and this is addobj.js

```
function addItems(arg1, arg2) {
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#addobj_btn').click(function() {  
var formURL = 'obiumap_addobj';
jQuery("#obiumap").submit(function(){
 return false;
 });
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "GET",
        data : { uid: jQuery('input[name=uid]').val() },
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            jQuery('#addobj-container').html(data);
            console.log("###### Drupal.attach #####");
            Drupal.attachBehaviors("#addobj-container");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
        }
    });

});

});
}
```

I really need autocomplete for that field but I don't now how to activate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Drupal's autocomplete, you need to modify form using [Form API '#ajax'](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). If you are doing it with your custom scripts, Form API will not know that field really belongs to your form, and will not handle field's calls.<sup>1</sup>

The way you should do it is:

1. In your form building function, create element with '#ajax' property, that will be responsible for loading your form part, or add it to existing element.
2. Also in your form building function, add an `if` that will check triggering element (`$form_state['triggering_element']`), and if that was your button, add entry in `$form_state` that new section should be visible.
3. If there is an entry mentioned in 2., output form part you want to be loaded with AJAX.
4. Use AJAX callback function **only** to select and return proper part of the form.

---

<sup>1</sup> Simplified explanation, of course.